# Error with arrays/matrix operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, runtime-error

I am trying to run the following code.  For those who know it, this is a try of the Ehrenfest Urn simulation.

```
import numpy as np
import random

C=5
L=2
# Here I create a matrix to be filled with zeros and after with numbers I want
b=np.zeros( (L,C) ) # line x column

A=[] # here I creat 2 lists to put random integer numbers on it
B=[]

i=1
while i<=10: # here I am filling list A (only) with 10 numbers
    A.append(i)
    i=i+1

for j in range(2):

    for i in range(5):  #here I want to choose random numbers between 1 and 10,

        Sort=random.randint(1,10)

        if i==0: # since there is no number on B, the first step, the number goes to B
            B.append(Sort)
            A.remove(Sort)
            print(len(A))

        if i>0:   # now each list A and B have numbers on it, so I will choose one number and see in which list it is
                if Sort in A:
                    B.append(Sort)
                    A.remove(Sort)
                else:
                    A.append(Sort)
                    B.remove(Sort)

            i=i+1
            b[j,i]=len(A) # here I want to add the lenght of the list A in a matrix, but then I get the error.
        j=j+1

print(b)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-4884a3da9648>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Public/Documents/Python Scripts/33.py', wdir='C:/Users/Public/Documents/Python Scripts')

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Public/Documents/Python Scripts/33.py", line 42, in <module>
b[j,i]=len(A) # here I want to add the lenght of the list A in a matrix

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5
```

What am I doing wrong with the arrays?
Is there anything to do with the identification of the numbers in the matrix?

Comment: A clear problem is your list A[] will have 11 slots, not 10 (zero inclusive); did you account for that?

Comment: Yes I did checked that =) But I have no idea where the problem is anymore

Comment: I believe Hpauji's answer should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error implies that `b.shape[1]` (axis 1) is 5; but `i` is 5.  Remember indexing starts at 0.

In the broader picture:

```
while i<5:  #here I want to choose random numbers between 1 and 10,
     ...
     i=i+1
     b[j,i] ...
```

at the last iteration `i==4`, you add one, and now it is 5, and gives the error.

Typically in Python we iterate with

```
 for i in range(5):
    b[j,i] ...
```

`range(5)` produces `[0,1,2,3,4]`.  You may have good reasons to use the while instead, but it's subject to the same bounds.

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that, thanks!!         I changed it in my code, but the same error appears again

Comment: Oh, now it worked somehow... I was getting another error related with the first A.remove but suddlently it worked...

Comment: Is it normal to have different errors if one does not change the code and run it a few times? I say this because, I ran the code 5 times and 2 of them I got the same error here, 2 other times I got the error with the A.remove and the last time it worked...

Comment: Since you are using `random` you are testing with different values.  Sounds like you still have a bug or two.